# How to get App Id from request Header in GAE application

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to get the application id from requestHeader it's returning as Null. Google App Engine doc confirms that they will be adding the some details in the request header in that the application id also there but I am not getting.

Here is what I tried.

```
String XAppEngineAppId = request
                    .getHeader("X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid");
            logger.info("APPID::" + XAppEngineAppId);
```

Comment: AFAIK those headers are only sent to internal calls like queues/cron requests. I dont think they send it for every request.

Answer (score 1):

The `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header is set only when called to apps hosted on the appspot.com domain.

Also if you are using the `java.net` API, you must set `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);` so that App Engine inserts the header automatically.

Documentation on this topic is available here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the App Identity Java API

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/

The application ID can be found using the ApiProxy.Environment.getAppId() method.

Comment: The external app connecting to the app in question also owned by you?